# java gui not displaying correctly

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a problem with the GUI after calling it from another method, I am making a game of dominoes.

In the picture here, the GUI is working fine and does what it is supposed to do, however in the second image I tried to use the exact same GUI however It is parsed through a different way ( I have a start screen, which will call the method and make the GUI visible). 
Here in the console, the tiles are stored in the allocated array and are also drawn onto the GUI

[image: First Image]

The second image here, the playerVSAI method is called in an actionlistener from the firstScreen() class. this class is just window which is displayed on the left. However the the console, the playerVSAI method seems to work as intended however the images of tiles are not displayed.

The method which does the stores the data into the array and draws the tiles onto the is the same one, I have attatched a snippet of the code below

```
        if(input2.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
    {

        //add selected input to gameboard
        gameboardX.add(0,player.get(input1));

        JLabel imageTile = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(rotate(bi,rotateDegree)));

        //place domino image to left, Y direction still the same, only shift X , 
        // shift X by turnCounter, as turnCounter++  larger amount can only shift outwards
        c.gridy = startingY;
        c.gridx = startingX - turnCounter ;

        //add image
        gui.add(imageTile,c);
        gui.revalidate();
    }
```

[image: Second Image]

[image: edited]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have called the setVisible(true); line at the end of adding elements to GUI.

Comment: It doesnt seem to make any difference if I have the setVisible(true); at the end, as even the first one (just trying out the gui and the method) works fine. However the second one ( gui and method  + extra GUI) doesnt work , this problem is also occurs when I try using a JMenubar to call a new instance of the GUI and a new method.

Comment: are you sure that this line if(input2.equalsIgnoreCase( " l ")) returns true to enter inside the if branch?

Comment: Yes, as I have tried it out, with just the GUI and method, I have attached an extra image, it is the image with the highlights. The first highlight is the position of the tile in which I want to play, and the second highlight is the position ( Left, Right, Up, Down)  so in this case L or l , which will then add the tile to the array, as well as get the selected image tile from the src file and draw it onto the GUI ( second part of highlight)

Answer (score 0):

This looks and feels like a threading problem, possibly a race condition between your thread and Swing's (but such things can happen just by running `setVisible` from the main thread).

Make sure that all the logic that starts the window is run from EDT and that no data is passed to Swing objects from other threads. The simplest architecture will be to put all your code into the `EventQueue#invokeLater`, later you can move to some form of synchronization (frankly, for a game of dominoes, I wouldn't... unless you have a massive artificial intelligence running one of the players).

Comment: Sorry could you explain how to as I am not familiar with this concept.

Comment: When working with Swing (and this is _very_ basic information, in fact the first you should learn when doing any Swing programming) you have to use a special, designated thread (so called - EDT) for any work that touches any of the swing objects.